# SSIS development packages with no BIDS

Tags: ssis

I just have a simple question:

I have a production server with SQL Server 2008 SP2 installed with no BIDS!

Installing just ONLY Visual Studio 2008, will allow me to create an Integration Service Project?
Or BIDS is absolutely a mandatory requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: SSIS is only available in the “Standard” and “Enterprise” editions.  Which version do you have?

Comment: It is Enterprise Edition. But that is not what I asked for. What I need to know if BIDS is strictly mandatory to developing a SSIS project.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2008 will let you create an Integration service Project

[image]

So no Bids isn't required but you have to have analysis services installed i believe to get that project type.

Comment: Thank you Dalm but may I ask you something?

Comment: Are you sure that on your physical machine is not installed Business Intelligence Development Studio?

Comment: I'm asking that because I have on my personal notebook Visual Studio that let me open a new Integration Services Project maybe just I have BIDS installed as well. I do not know if I made myself clear.

Comment: At home I dont have Bids Installed I use VS 10 (I dont have VS 2008)  Here at work I have VS 2008 and Bids installed. My VS 2008 Lets me Create SSIS Projects.  If you installed the SQL Server 2008 R2 client tools, you will see the Business Intelligence project templates in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Ok.. I thank you very much for your help. You cleared my mind. Thanks again!